# Abbreviations management

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I need to deal with a great number of abbreviations, so I would like to create a spreadsheet where all of them are automatically ordered as I enter each in a new cell. Also, the whole row corresponding to such cell must be moved along when ordered alphabetically.

I am just supposing this is the best way to proceed, so any ideas will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have something like:

[image]

Out editing procedure says to enter the full text in column **B** and then the abbreviation next to it in column **A**.  First place the following sub in a **standard module**:

```
Sub Macro1()
   Dim N As Long
   N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   Columns("A:B").Select
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A" & N), _
      SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
   With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
      .SetRange Range("A1:B" & N)
      .Header = xlYes
      .MatchCase = False
      .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
      .SortMethod = xlPinYin
      .Apply
   End With
End Sub
```

Then place this event macro in the **worksheet code area**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim A As Range
   Set A = Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count)
   If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   If Target.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then Exit Sub

   Application.EnableEvents = False
      Call Macro1
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Once macros are enabled, changes to cells in column **A** will cause the table to re-sort.

Comment: First of all, thank you for replying.
I would like to be able to sort them out using any column, as long as the whole row is moved along at the same time.
Also, in case I wanted to sort them using any feature other than alphabetical order, e.g. by descending number of letters, how should I modificate the code so that it works?
Finally, should I paste the code before starting to write down anything, and then enter the my next word in the next cell available in the first column A?